# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) - Tribe Events

Tags: wordpress

I am sure I am being an indiot but I can't spot what is causing the error. It is on line 106 which is third from bottom. Any help in spotting the error would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rs_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function rs_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'menu-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/menus.css' );
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_posts');
function my_posts($query) {
    if ((is_tag() || is_category()) && (!isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) || !$query->query_vars['post_type'])) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'any');
    }
    return $query;
}

// Enqueue and tell WP to load child theme custom javascript file
// if ( !is_admin() ) { // instruction to only load if it is not the admin area
    function rs_custom_scripts() {
        // Get current theme version
        $_theme     = wp_get_theme();
        $_theme_ver = $_theme->get( 'Version' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'rs_custom_scripts', 
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_scripts.js', 
            array( 'jquery' ), 
            $_theme_ver, 
            true);

        wp_enqueue_script( 'rs_custom_menu_script', 
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/menu-handler.js', 
            array( 'jquery' ), 
            $_theme_ver, 
            true);
        // More custom scripts can be enqueued here
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rs_custom_scripts', 1000);
// }


// TGM Plugin Activation
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php';
add_action( 'tgmpa_register', 'riseandshine_register_required_plugins' );
function riseandshine_register_required_plugins() {

    $plugins = array(

        array(
            'name'               => 'Divi Login',
            'slug'               => 'DiviLogin',
            'source'             => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/plugins/DiviLogin.zip',
            'required'           => true,
            'version'            => '1.0',
            'force_activation'   => false,
            'force_deactivation' => false,
            'external_url'       => 'http://divi.space/',
            'is_callable'        => '',
        ),

        array(
            'name'      => 'Wordpress Countdown Widget',
            'slug'      => 'wordpress-countdown-widget',
            'required'  => true,
        ),

        array(
            'name'        => 'Recipe Card',
            'slug'        => 'recipe-card',
            'required'  => true,
        ),

        array(
            'name'        => 'Restaurant Reservations',
            'slug'        => 'restaurant-reservations',
            'required'  => true,
        ),

        array(
            'name'        => 'WooCommerce',
            'slug'        => 'woocommerce',
            'required'  => true,
        ),

    );

    $config = array(
        'id'           => 'tgmpa',
        'default_path' => '',
        'menu'         => 'tgmpa-install-plugins',
        'parent_slug'  => 'themes.php',
        'capability'   => 'edit_theme_options',
        'has_notices'  => true,
        'dismissable'  => true,
        'dismiss_msg'  => '',
        'is_automatic' => false,
        'message'      => '',

    );

    tgmpa( $plugins, $config );
}
function my_et_builder_post_types( $post_types ) {
    $post_types[] = 'events';
    $post_types[] = 'tribe_events';

    return $post_types;
}
add_filter( 'et_builder_post_types', 'my_et_builder_post_types' );
```

Comment: I don't see any error, copying the code snippet into a file runs it without error too. It could be just an invisible utf8 character that messes up your file. You can try to copy&past the function back from here into your file, or just retype the relevant lines to get rid of such a character.

Comment: I have tried copying and pasting back in from here but still getting the error when I update

Comment: 1. Comment the code from Line 102 to 108 and see if the error still appears. And it does, keep on commenting chunks of code incremantally, until you cease getting errors. Do this commenting code from down to up.

2. Put debug statements (echo, prints etc. ) at multiple places to see which get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because of braces in the file included by `require_once`

```
 require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php';
```

Comment: The [`include` and `require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statements aren't functions, they are language constructs. They don't need braces.

Comment: sure, but they include code which could contain braces

Comment: You are right, that's a possibility. I took the liberty of editing your answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Apologies, I am quite new to this. What are you suggesting I try?

Comment: I would recommend to double check the code in dirname( \__FILE\__ ) . '/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php';

Comment: Looking for invisible characters?

Comment: looking for incorrect braces. In my experience, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) is raised when improper braces were added or missing usually

Comment: I couldn't find anything so restored from a backup and all is well again.

Comment: could you diff the old and new copies if possible ? Wonder about the root cause of the error

Comment: I can't spot anything different but here is the code that worked.

Comment: Had to remove bits to fit it in a comment

// TGM Plugin Activation
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php';
add_action( 'tgmpa_register', 'riseandshine_register_required_plugins' );
function riseandshine_register_required_plugins() {
}
function my_et_builder_post_types( $post_types ) {
    $post_types[] = 'events';
    $post_types[] = 'tribe_events';
     
    return $post_types;
}
add_filter( 'et_builder_post_types', 'my_et_builder_post_types' );